# Button for duplicating tabs in a QTabWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtabwidget

I have a program that uses an input tab with multiple entry boxes for a user to fill out, and when those entry boxes are filled in, I hit run and another program will run the data entered. I'd like for my program to have a tab button with a plus sign that will duplicate the tabs dynamically so that I can run multiple instances. I'd like for each tab to use the same name, but have a variant at the end - e.g. "EntryBox0", "EntryBox1", "EntryBox2".

Is there an easy way to do this, while keeping the formatting (widget positions) the same in all tabs?

My first thought was to code the multiple tabs manually and have a hide/unhide button for each tab, however that would be a lot more code.

[image]

I'd like to add the + sign next to "Tab 2". All of the tabs will identical. The widgets will have same name, but have a dynamic number at the end to identify which tab is being used.

---

```
from Stage import Ui_Form
from Tabs import Ui_TabPage

class TabPage(QWidget, Ui_TabPage):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

class Stage(QMainWindow, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        button = QtWidgets.QToolButton()
        button.setToolTip('Add New Tab')
        button.clicked.connect(self.addNewTab)
        button.setIcon(self.style().standardIcon(
            QtWidgets.QStyle.SP_DialogYesButton))
        self.tabWidget.setCornerWidget(button, QtCore.Qt.TopRightCorner)
        self.addNewTab()

    def addNewTab(self):
        text = 'Tab %d' % (self.tabWidget.count() + 1)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(TabPage(self.tabWidget), text)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Stage()
    window.setGeometry(600, 100, 300, 200)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `QTabWidget` class has a [setCornerWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html#setCornerWidget) method that can be used to add a button to the tab-bar. This can only be positioned at either the left or right end of the tab-bar (rather than after the last tab) - but, to me, that seems more user-friendly, since the button won't move when a new tab is added. The tabs themselves can be easily duplicated by creating a separate class for the tab page.

Below is a simple demo script that implements that:

[image: screenshot]

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class TabPage(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        group = QtWidgets.QGroupBox('Monty Python')
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(group)
        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(group)
        grid.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel('Enter a name:'), 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel('Choose a number:'), 0, 1)
        grid.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLineEdit(), 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(QtWidgets.QComboBox(), 1, 1)
        grid.addWidget(QtWidgets.QPushButton('Click Me!'), 1, 2)
        grid.addWidget(QtWidgets.QSpinBox(), 2, 0)
        grid.addWidget(QtWidgets.QPushButton('Clear Text'), 2, 2)
        grid.addWidget(QtWidgets.QTextEdit(), 3, 0, 1, 3)

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.tabs = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.tabs)
        button = QtWidgets.QToolButton()
        button.setToolTip('Add New Tab')
        button.clicked.connect(self.addNewTab)
        button.setIcon(self.style().standardIcon(
            QtWidgets.QStyle.SP_DialogYesButton))
        self.tabs.setCornerWidget(button, QtCore.Qt.TopRightCorner)
        self.addNewTab()

    def addNewTab(self):
        text = 'Tab %d' % (self.tabs.count() + 1)
        self.tabs.addTab(TabPage(self.tabs), text)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(600, 100, 300, 200)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: That's what I am looking for, my other question is, I have already made my tab with QtDesigner using layouts and scrollareas, is there a way to directly import it into the tab class? In other words I don't want to have to .addwidget for each label/lineedits that I have?

Comment: @dre. I assume you added all the widgets to a page inside the tab-widget in Qt Designer. If so, you need to move all those widgets into a new tab-page widget and save it separately. An easy way to do this, is to select the tab in the Object Inspector, then hold down the shift key and click on the last child-widget under that tab. You can then drag and drop the widgets as a group onto a new form and set a layout on it. All the old tabs should be removed from the tab-widget. Then you can use pyuic to generate a module for the tab-page class which can be imported just like the main gui class.

Comment: I've updated my post with code you provided, I am trying to follow what you are saying. I've copied all of the tab to a new form in QtDesigner and saved as UI and used pyuic to generate the module, I am not getting anything, I am obviously doing something wrong, probably importing it incorrectly.

Comment: @dre. You should have two separate forms: one for the main gui (which will be a QMainWindow), and one for the tab-page (which will be a QWidget). These will both need to be re-generated with pyuic, so you can then import the two gui classes they contain.

Comment: @dre. I have edited the code in your question to give a rough idea what it should look like. Hopefully that should make it clear now.

Comment: Okay, I got it. How do I access widget names on different tabs?

Comment: @dre. Something like e.g. `self.tabWidget.widget(index).lineEdit.text()`.

Comment: Thank you, works well. Now just need to figure out how to make the tabs in certain order, with one tab being part of main GUI and the others are the duplicated tabs