# Inserting a tab into QTabWidget from a pre-defined layout

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, qt-designer

I am trying to add tabs to my QTabWidget dynamically and the simple thing I want to do is duplicate the 1st preset tab that I already have. Now before you lead me to this question: [Button for duplicating tabs in a QTabWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47556122/button-for-duplicating-tabs-in-a-qtabwidget), hear me out.

I don't want to manually duplicate the tab. The tab that I have is detailed and can have major updates made to it at any time, I would like to simply edit it in the QTDesigner and then perhaps duplicate it dynamically or simply insert the given form into the QTabWidget. I've tried many things (i.e.: Trying to make a separate form and importing it, designing my own tab page class [which worked but it's not what I'm looking for], literally copying the tabWidget and trying to add it) but none of them seem to do the trick.

I just need a tab to be inserted via a pre-defined UI.

**EDIT:**

After creating a form via the QtDesigner software and exporting it into a python file I get this code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'newTab.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.2
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(810, 672)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Form)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.testIdFrame = QtWidgets.QFrame(Form)
        self.testIdFrame.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 622))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI Black")
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(True)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.testIdFrame.setFont(font)
        self.testIdFrame.setStyleSheet("background: transparent;")
        self.testIdFrame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.testIdFrame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.testIdFrame.setObjectName("testIdFrame")
        self.atpDropBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.testIdFrame)
        self.atpDropBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 20, 98, 31))
        self.atpDropBox.setObjectName("atpDropBox")
        self.snLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.testIdFrame)
        self.snLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 30, 32, 21))
        self.snLabel.setObjectName("snLabel")
        self.workOrderLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.testIdFrame)
        self.workOrderLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 75, 21))
        self.workOrderLabel.setObjectName("workOrderLabel")
        self.powerSupplyLabel1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.testIdFrame)
        self.powerSupplyLabel1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 70, 101, 21))
        self.powerSupplyLabel1.setObjectName("powerSupplyLabel1")
        self.snTextEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.testIdFrame)
        self.snTextEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 20, 131, 31))
        self.snTextEdit.setStyleSheet("QTextEdit {\n"
"border: 1px solid black;\n"
"border-radius:5px; \n"
"}")
        self.snTextEdit.setObjectName("snTextEdit")
        self.voltageTextEdit1 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.testIdFrame)
        self.voltageTextEdit1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 60, 101, 31))
        self.voltageTextEdit1.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.voltageTextEdit1.setStyleSheet("QTextEdit {\n"
"border: 1px solid black;\n"
"border-radius:5px; \n"
"}")
        self.voltageTextEdit1.setObjectName("voltageTextEdit1")
        self.voltageLabel1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.testIdFrame)
        self.voltageLabel1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 70, 71, 21))
        self.voltageLabel1.setObjectName("voltageLabel1")
        self.voltageLabel2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.testIdFrame)
        self.voltageLabel2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 110, 71, 21))
        self.voltageLabel2.setObjectName("voltageLabel2")
        self.voltageTextEdit2 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.testIdFrame)
        self.voltageTextEdit2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 100, 101, 31))
        self.voltageTextEdit2.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.voltageTextEdit2.setStyleSheet("QTextEdit {\n"
"border: 1px solid black;\n"
"border-radius:5px; \n"
"}")
        self.voltageTextEdit2.setObjectName("voltageTextEdit2")
        self.powerSupplyLabel2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.testIdFrame)
        self.powerSupplyLabel2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 110, 101, 21))
        self.powerSupplyLabel2.setObjectName("powerSupplyLabel2")
        self.currentLabel2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.testIdFrame)
        self.currentLabel2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 110, 81, 21))
        self.currentLabel2.setObjectName("currentLabel2")
        self.currentLabel1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.testIdFrame)
        self.currentLabel1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 70, 91, 21))
        self.currentLabel1.setObjectName("currentLabel1")
        self.currentTextEdit1 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.testIdFrame)
        self.currentTextEdit1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 60, 101, 31))
        self.currentTextEdit1.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.currentTextEdit1.setStyleSheet("QTextEdit {\n"
"border: 1px solid black;\n"
"border-radius:5px; \n"
"}")
        self.currentTextEdit1.setObjectName("currentTextEdit1")
        self.currentTextEdit2 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.testIdFrame)
        self.currentTextEdit2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 100, 101, 31))
        self.currentTextEdit2.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.currentTextEdit2.setStyleSheet("QTextEdit {\n"
"border: 1px solid black;\n"
"border-radius:5px; \n"
"}")
        self.currentTextEdit2.setObjectName("currentTextEdit2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.testIdFrame)
        self.RXFrame = QtWidgets.QFrame(Form)
        self.RXFrame.setStyleSheet("background: transparent;")
        self.RXFrame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.RXFrame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.RXFrame.setObjectName("RXFrame")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.RXFrame)
        self.TXFrame = QtWidgets.QFrame(Form)
        self.TXFrame.setStyleSheet("background: transparent;")
        self.TXFrame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.TXFrame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.TXFrame.setObjectName("TXFrame")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.TXFrame)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.snLabel.setText(_translate("Form", "SN:"))
        self.workOrderLabel.setText(_translate("Form", "Work Order:"))
        self.powerSupplyLabel1.setText(_translate("Form", "Power Supply 1:"))
        self.voltageLabel1.setText(_translate("Form", "Voltage [V]:"))
        self.voltageLabel2.setText(_translate("Form", "Voltage [V]:"))
        self.powerSupplyLabel2.setText(_translate("Form", "Power Supply 2:"))
        self.currentLabel2.setText(_translate("Form", "Current [mA]:"))
        self.currentLabel1.setText(_translate("Form", "Current [mA]:"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In my MainWindow class I import the Ui_Form from the newly generated python file which contains the contents of the new tab that I would like to duplicate.
This is where I get stuck.. I call the function that will build my tabs for me:

```
def buildTabs(self, numberOfTabs): 
    for dut in range(numberOfTabs): 
        text = ('TAB ' + ascii_uppercase[dut]) 
        self.ui.tabWidget.addTab(Ui_Form(), text)
```

The tab widget is in the ui of the main window.

I don't understand how I can turn the Ui_Form() into a Ui_TabPage or a QWidget like shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47556122/button-for-duplicating-tabs-in-a-qtabwidget)

QT Designer Form:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2Ta1.png)

Comment: "Trying to make a separate form and importing it": from what you're describing, that's exactly what you need, besides making a class that dynamically creates child widgets based on some information (number of buttons, items in comboboxes, etc.). Why didn't it worked for you?

Comment: This was yesterday and I've tried many other things after, but If I remember correctly; it gave me an error because of Ui_Form not being compatible with QWidget. Maybe I was doing something wrong in the process.

Comment: I need a class that inherits from QWidget and I can't get that to work with a form.

Comment: please share your code where you attempted to do it and add as well the error.

Comment: I've edited the question and added the import process of the form. That's where my problem is coming from. I went deeper on this yesterday but could not get anywhere. P.S: I'm completely new to PyQt so forgive me lol

Comment: It also gives me an error when I call setupUi() function of the Form: 'Ui_Form' object has no attribute 'setObjectName'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files generated by pyuic are *form classes*, they are actually standard python `object` classes, and they need a QWidget instance (or whatever class used in Designer for that ui, such as a QDialog) to "build" them.

```
def buildTabs(self, numberOfTabs): 
    for dut in range(numberOfTabs): 
        page = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        page.ui = Ui_Form()
        page.ui.setupUi(page)        
        text = ('TAB ' + ascii_uppercase[dut])
        self.ui.tabWidget.addTab(page, text)
```

Consider that PyQt and PySide cannot be mixed, so if you're using PyQt the command is `pyuic`, while with PySide the command is `pyside2-uic`.

Note that if you need further interaction with the tab *pages*, it's usually better to subclass them:

```
class PageOne(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.someButton.clicked.connect(self.someFunction)
        # ...
```

Or better, with the multiple inheritance method, which avoids to constantly access ui elements through the `ui` "sub-object":

```
class PageOne(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.someButton.clicked.connect(self.someFunction)
        # ...
```

And then:

```
def buildTabs(self, numberOfTabs): 
    for dut in range(numberOfTabs): 
        page = PageOne()
        text = ('TAB ' + ascii_uppercase[dut])
        self.ui.tabWidget.addTab(page, text)
```

Comment: After running the code above it gave me this error:   [I've also attached the QtDesigner screenshot]                                            
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  QVBoxLayout(): too many arguments
  QVBoxLayout(QWidget): argument 1 has unexpected type 'PySide2.QtWidgets.QWidget'

Comment: If you're using PySide, you cannot use PyQt's pyuic to create files, as PyQt and PySide modules cannot be used together. Use pyside's own command, which I believe is `pyside2-uic`.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH BRO! I had tried all these different solutions and doing the pyside import was what that was missing.